# Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: php, bash, ssh, phpseclib

I'm trying to execute SSH commands through a PHP application.

Through the PHP application, I type "./SSDownload.sh".
Through my terminal SSH, I type "./SSDownload.sh".

**SSDownload.sh contains:**

```
cd /var/www/html/dev/media/mp3/$1
spotify-to-mp3 songs.txt
```

**Through my terminal SSH, I get this response:**

```
Resolving "fancy iggy azalea"
Searching "fancy iggy azalea" on Grooveshark
"Iggy Azalea - Fancy (feat. Charli XCX)" will be downloaded

Downloading tracks...
[1/1] Iggy Azalea - Fancy (feat. Charli  100% [==================================] Time: 00:00:01
Download complete
```

The file downloads successfully, and places the files in the correct directory.

I tried the same with PHP using the following code:

```
include('Net/SSH2.php');
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('iphere');
if (!$ssh->login('root', 'password')) {
exit('Login Failed');
}

echo "1 : " . $ssh->exec('./SSDownload.sh ' . $_GET['player']) . "<br />";
```

*Output:*

```
Resolving "fancy iggy azalea" Searching "fancy iggy azalea" on Grooveshark "Iggy Azalea - Fancy (feat. Charli XCX)" will be downloaded Downloading tracks... [0;31;49mInappropriate ioctl for device[0m [0;32;49mDownload complete[0m
```

The file does not download successfully, and does not place the files in the correct directory.

I'd like to bring your attention to "**Inappropriate ioctl for device**", whatever it means.

Why are the responses different? How can I go about fixing it?

Comment: Stealing is bad, mkay

Comment: @zerkms It's for a spotify application :3

Comment: How is ssh involved here?

Comment: @Kenster Well I want to know why executing the same script on the same machine gives two different results. SSH is involved since both applications are using SSH to execute the script. Thanks.

Comment: The PHP application is using ssh? Could you add the relevant source code from the PHP application?

Comment: @Kenster Added, I've tried many different ways to SSH to the server through PHP, but all give the same "Inappropriate ioctl for device". Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Please also add the contents of `SSDownload.sh`.

Comment: @hek2mgl SSDownload.sh is the same as script.sh. I updated the question to fix

Comment: Ah, ok. Let me try to reproduce that...

Comment: @hek2mgl Keep me posted :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An "ioctl" is a POSIX operation to send a control command to a device ("I/O control"). The "Inappropriate ioctl" error means that the program sent an ioctl to a device that wasn't correct in some way. The question is what ioctls this spotify program may be using that are dependent on how it's run.

When you run the spotify program from the command line, it has a TTY. When your PHP code launches the program, it doesn't have a TTY. It's probably sending an ioctl to its standard output for some reason, expecting standard output to be a tty. My guess is that it's using an ioctl to get the terminal width so that it can display that progress bar graphic.

There are two ways to fix this. You could check the documentation for this spotify program to see if it has a noninteractive mode or batch mode or quiet mode that disables printing the progress bar. That might avoid performing the ioctl that's failing.

The other fix is to have PHP request a pty (pseudo-TTY) for the ssh session. I'm not a PHP coder, but [this page](http://phpseclib.bantux.org/api/master/Net_SSH2.html) appears to describe the Net_SSH2 API, and it [lists a function to enable requesting a PTY](http://phpseclib.bantux.org/api/master/Net_SSH2.html#method_enablePTY) for calls to exec().

Comment: I'm testing it out now

Comment: The answer is basically correct. I tried to reproduce the problem and also stumbled upon `enablePTY()`. When I use it, the command simply outputs a `1`.. Wondering why currently.

Comment: Kudos to you. It worked. Really appreciate it, thanks!

Solution:
$ssh->enablePTY(); 
$ssh->exec('./SSDownload.sh ' . $_GET['player']); 
echo $ssh->read();

Comment: @Toby One importing thing you need to fix: You need to use `escapeshellarg($_GET['player'])` .. Otherwise one could use the `player` variable to execute arbitrary commands from remote

Comment: @hek2mgl `When I use it, the command simply outputs a 1` If spotify is checking the terminal width to format the progress line, it may be that the PTY is getting a default terminal width that's not a reasonable value. On the page I linked to, there are functions to set the PTY's width and height. They may help.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
echo "1 : " . $ssh->exec('/bin/bash -c '.escapeshellarg('./SSDownload.sh ' . escapeshellarg($_GET['player']))) . "<br />";
```